# Wanted to filter out the tag from scenario outline in karate when i am running command line maven : mvn clean test Dkarate.options="-- tags @stage"

Tags: command, karate

My requirement is i want to run example table based the karate.env.

Feature : testing filter scenario

Scenario outline : test something in

@stage
Examples :
|Name|
| stage|

@pros
Examples :
|name|
|prod|

Comment: if the linked answer does not answer your question, please assume that what you want is not supported by karate. or make your next question more clear with a better example